# New tag: [nonstandard-models]

Tags: discussion, tagging

Today I came across the following question

- [Infinite set of standard primes as the set of standard prime divisors of a nonstandard number](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/542411/8348)

and in attempting to appropriately tag it, I felt myself at a bit of a loss.  The tags [logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic), [model-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/model-theory) and [peano-axioms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/peano-axioms) each seemed to fit (and possibly even [divisibility](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divisibility)).  But it concerned a particular concept that didn't seem to match up with any of these (either individually or in combination, in my opinion).  The [nonstandard-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nonstandard-analysis) tag seemed much too removed in its scope.

I therefore introduced the [nonstandard-models](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nonstandard-models) tag.

A [quick search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=nonstandard+arithmetic+is:question) resulted in several questions for which this tag might be appropriate, though I will refrain from re-tagging these questions for the time being.

I am therefore requesting the community opinion on the following:

1. Is this tag worthwhile?
2. If the majority opinion to the above is "yes", can someone better versed in the subject suggest an appropriate tag-wiki?
3. If the consensus to the first is "no", then how should one appropriately tag questions about nonstandard models of arithmetic?

Comment: If a separate tag is to exist, (nonstandard-arithmetic) is the direct analogue to (NS-A).  Currently, no nonstandard tag except NSA exists on MO, including questions asked by cognoscenti who well understand the distinction: http://mathoverflow.net/search?q=nonstandard+arithmetic .   As far as I know non-logicians don't make a serious distinction between NSA and NSArithmetic and often think of the first as having been built from the second.

Comment: I knew that the NSA are monitoring us. And that they use non-standard ways to collect and analyze the data.

Comment: @zyx: I hadn't thought of checking MO for tips. I'll have to spend some time looking through their [nonstandard-analysis] tag, though their usage will naturally be more informed. My gut feeling is that _for math.SE_ the concepts are a bit too distinct; at the very least our [nonstandard-analysis] tag-wki would have to be expanded to include this.  (Of course, then merging and synonymising the tags would be quick and simple.)

Comment: @Arthur: I feel that the non-standard models of arithmetics should fall well within the bounds of the Peano tag and logic (or model-theory).

Comment: Interestingly, the tag has one follower, nine questions and a Wiki.